# How to enable HondaLink in the 2019 Honda Accord?

Tags: honda, accord

I'm trying to connect the HondaLink on my android phone to the Honda Accord 2019. In order to do that, the app says that I have to ensure that HondaLink is enabled. But I don't where or how to enable HondaLink in the car touchscreen device. There seems to be no way to find this setting.

Comment: You may find this work a read : https://www.rensselaerhonda.com/what-is-hondalink-app/

Comment: @SolarMike thank you for the link. But it doesn't tell where or how to 'enable' HondaLink.